# How to use PHP_CodeSniffer with XAMPP?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I am running XAMPP with windows XP. I just download PHP_CodeSniffer and cannot figure out how to run it.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**documentation**](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.intro.php) has it all.

**EDIT:**

The first line of `phpcs` is:

```
#!@php_bin@
```

you need to replace `@php_bin@` with correct path to php to make a meaningful shebang as(In linux):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Since windows does not have the concept of shebang, you can delete the first line of `phpcs`and then run it as:

```
C:\>path\to\php\bin\php.exe path\to\phpcs path\to\file\to\analyze
```

Comment: I have read that document, however it seems that doc is for environment in UNIX.

For example, I cannot run phpcs /path/to/code/myfile.php under SHELL command window of XAMPP.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_CodeSniffer-1.3.0a1\scripts>phpcs.bat
'"@php_bin@"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please clarify/improve what the first line should be on Windows. I don't want to hard code the path to the file I wan to analyze within my phpcs.bat like you show here.