# php codesniffer + xampp: Missing PEAR/Exception.php

Tags: php, xampp, phpcodesniffer

I followed exactly what's in: [How to use PHP_CodeSniffer with XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611865/how-to-use-php-codesniffer-with-xampp) (no more no less)

But i encounter this error:

Warning: require_once(PEAR/Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\path\to\htdocs\php-codesniffer\CodeSniffer\Exception.php on line 17

Comment: Do you have pear installed ? and what does it said when you do `var_dump(PEAR);` ?

Comment: i think not. this returns string(4). BTW, i've installed pear via go-pear and i can see the package manager. it seems that its not integrated to php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out what's wrong. PEAR is not initially enabled in xampp.

```
include_path = ".;C:\Documents\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

Also consider this if your changing the include_path value in your php scripts via ini_set.